# NBCJ Passwordchecker

Tags: python, strings, validation

```
import sys,math,re

def check_password_length(password):

    length = str(len(password))
    global password_length_good

    if len (password) < 8:
        print("Password should be at least 8 characters long")
        print("Password is only" ,length, " character(s) long")
        password_length_good = False;
    else:
        print("Password is" ,length, " character(s)")
        password_length_good = True;

def check_password_uppercase(password):

        global UpperLength

        UpperLength = len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',password))

        print("Your password contains" ,UpperLength, "upper case character(s)")

        if UpperLength == 0:
            print("No Uppercase characters.")

def check_password_numbers(password):

    global digits
    digits = len(re.findall(r'[0-9]',password))

    print("Your password contains" , digits, "number(s)")

    if digits == 0:
        print("No digits in the password")





def main():
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    check_password_length(password)
    check_password_uppercase(password)
    check_password_numbers(password)
```

Comment: Please describe your code and say what is your question?

Comment: Are you just trying to validate passwords or do you need to tell the user how long his/her password is?

Comment: You'll probably need to explain what NBCJ means - it's not an abbreviation I've seen before.

Answer (score 1):

I started by removing unnecessary includes (math and sys).  And then I went ahead and created a containing function for your `check_password` that gives you one place where you are handling input/output regarding your password. It makes it more readable.  I even set it up so it will return if the password ended up being valid. This is useful if you need to validate a password somewhere else in your program (or have the user keep entering passwords until they type in a valid one.  I also didn't include the stuff about printing the number of characters in the password because your user won't care if they have 10 characters in their password, if their password is valid.

```
import re

def check_password_length(password):
    return len(password) > 8

def check_password_uppercase(password):
    return len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',password)) > 0

def check_password_numbers(password):
    return len(re.findall(r'[0-9]',password)) > 0

def check_password(password):
    error_message = ""
    if not check_password_length(password):
        error_message += "Your password must exceed 8 characters.\n"
    if not check_password_uppercase(password):
        error_message += "Your password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter.\n"
    if not check_password_numbers(password):
        error_message += "Your password must contain at least 1 number.\n"
    print(error_message if error_message else "Your password is valid.")
    return not len(error_message)

def main():
    check_password(input("Enter your password: "))

main()
```